# Prefix all lines with the first word in a file

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I want to prefix all the lines of a file (except first line) using the first word in a file.

Input:

```
x.o: x.cpp /u/a.h 
/b.h \
/c.h \
```

output:

```
x.o: x.cpp /u/a.h \
x.o: /b.h \
x.o: /c.h \
```

Can anyone please help me how to solve the above using sed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with GNU sed:

```
sed -r '1 {h; s/ .*//; x}; 1!{G; s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/}' infile
```

Or as a separate script:

*parse.sed*

```
1 {                         # run block for first line only
  h                         # save copy of line in hold space
  s/ .*//                   # remove redundant part
  x                         # swap prefix to hold space
}

1! {                        # when not first line
  G                         # append prefix to pattern space
  s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/   # reorganize so prefix is the prefix
}
```

Run it like this:

```
 sed -rf parse.sed infile
```

Output:

```
x.o: x.cpp /u/a.h 
x.o: /b.h \
x.o: /c.h \
```

Comment: +1 I'm always impressed by non-trivial sed scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 'print $prefix; ($prefix) = /^(.+? )/ if 1..1' INPUT.TXT
```

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure whether I can use above solution in a makefile. I want to use sed command to achieve above.

Comment: @Naga, there's nothing magic about sed in a makefile. perl (or awk or ...) is just an external tool like sed.